# Spawning a new process with an asyncio loop from within the asyncio loop running in the current process

Tags: python, linux, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm a little confused about the interaction between multiprocessing and asyncio. My goal is to be able to spawn async processes from other async processes. Here is a small example:

```
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process


async def sleep_n(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(n)


def async_sleep(n):
    # This does not work
    #   
    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(sleep_n(n))

    # This works
    asyncio.run(sleep_n(n))


async def spawn_another():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    p = Process(target=async_sleep, args=(5,))
    p.start()
    p.join()


def spawn():
    # This does not work
    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(spawn_another())

    # This works
    asyncio.run(spawn_another())


def doit():
    p = Process(target=spawn)
    p.start()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    doit()
```

If I replace `asyncio.run` with `get_event_loop().run_until_complete`, I get the following error: "The event loop is already running". This is raised from `loop.run_until_complete(sleep_n(n))`. What's the difference between these two?

(NB: the reason I care about this is, if it makes a difference in the proposed remedy, is because in my actual code the thing I'm running in async is a `grpc.aio` client which apparently requires me to use `run_until_complete` or otherwise I get an error about a Future that's attached to a different event loop. That said, this is just an aside and not really material to the question above.)

Comment: What Python version and OS are you using? All variations of this code (run_until_complete vs run) work for me using Python3.11 on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.11 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've pinned it down. Its an issue with how multiprocessing works on Linux vs Windows/MacOS

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods):

> ### Contexts and start methods
>
> Depending on the platform, multiprocessing supports three ways to
> start a process. These start methods are
>
> - `spawn`
>
>   The parent process starts a fresh Python interpreter process. The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run
>   the process object’s run() method. In particular, unnecessary file
>   descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited.
>   Starting a process using this method is rather slow compared to using
>   fork or forkserver.
>
>   Available on Unix and Windows. **The default on Windows and macOS.**
> - `fork`
>
>   The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter. The child process, when it begins, is effectively
>   identical to the parent process. All resources of the parent are
>   inherited by the child process. Note that safely forking a
>   multithreaded process is problematic.
>
>   Available on Unix only. **The default on Unix.**
> - `forkserver`
>
>   When the program starts and selects the forkserver start method, a server process is started. From then on, whenever a new
>   process is needed, the parent process connects to the server and
>   requests that it fork a new process. The fork server process is single
>   threaded so it is safe for it to use os.fork(). No unnecessary
>   resources are inherited.
>
>   Available on Unix platforms which support passing file descriptors over Unix pipes.

So this works on MacOS and Windows because the default is `spawn`, versus it fails on Linux where the default is `fork`. Because we're using `fork`, the entire set of data is being mapped, meaning that we're sharing the existing already instantiated local event loop in the new process. That's why the event loop states that it is already be running (and asyncio is by design non-re-entrant).

To get around this you can set the mode to `spawn` manually in the main. When we use this mode, the interpreter will be newly invoked, meaning that there will be no existing event loop to conflict on.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing as mp
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    doit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've found an answer, and although your solution did not work for me, the explanation about the difference between how Linux and Microsoft handle processes inspired me to find a solution.

I'm unsure what might be the cause, but I'm almost certain that it has to do something with me trying to spawn multiprocessing.Process instance from within a 3-4 level nested async function call and then submitting for a target function a sync function that calls asyncio.run(). For some reason it still shared an event loop. Be that as it may, I've found a solution with [aiomultiprocess](https://aiomultiprocess.omnilib.dev/en/stable/guide.html) library. It creates an instace of AsyncIO loop within each process.